# What is the difference between prove, show and find?

Tags: proof-writing

I have been practicing for a proof test. The more I practice the more I see those three words: Proof, Show and Find.
Is there a formal definition on what a question is asking for when each of these words is used?

Comment: "Prove" = "Show", for starters. "Prove the following statement", and, "Show that the following statement is true", are two ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: "find" means usually recognizing a pattern or having a special idea leading to a conjecture.

Comment: Find can also be used for equations and similar: "Find a real number $x$ such that /.../", "Find a function $f$ satisfying /.../"